# Moving Mozilla Thunderbird email accounts from one computer to another

Tags: email, thunderbird, user-accounts, transfer

I have my Mozilla Thunderbird full with email accounts. That's over 200 different accounts that I wish to move on my new laptop.

I tried to find a way to export them but Thunderbird only has an Import option.

I wonder if there is a way I could somehow move all of them from one Windows 7 installation to another Windows 7 installation.

Thank you,
Maya White

Answer (score 2):

Copy your Thunderbird "profile" folder to the new computer. On Windows, it is kept at `%AppData%\Thunderbird`.

- [Moving Thunderbird Data to a New Computer](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/moving-thunderbird-data-to-a-new-computer) – Mozilla Support
- [Profiles TB](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-tb) – Mozilla Support
- [Moving your profile folder - Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Moving_your_profile_folder_-_Thunderbird) – MozzilaZine

Answer (score 1):

Use MozBackup  http://mozbackup.jasnapaka.com/
Does a great job moving everything or just parts.Easy to use and never had any problems in dozens of uses.